# Rails no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header issue with unhandled socket.io url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, socket.io, cors, webrtc

I am testing out a webrtc demo for rails, but am having terrible connectivity issues. I have tried multiple things online but cannot crack this, it might be a simple mistake or a fundamental misunderstanding, but what I have done is this:

webrtc-rails using NodeJS and socket.io

I am using localhost:3000 for the home url of the page but am trying to connect from client to server via localhost:2013. I have two error messages at the moment:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

and

```
info  - unhandled socket.io url   (when  running node server.js)
```

My set up is this:

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
}).listen(2013);
```

client.js

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost:2013');

socket.on("created", function (){
  console.log("On Created");
  isInitiator = true;
  console.log('isInitiator', isInitiator);
})
```

application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

config.ru

```
require 'rack/cors'

use Rack::Cors do

  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
        :headers => :any,
        :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options, :patch]
  end

end
```

I have updated all my gems and socket.io. I keep wondering whether there is a problem finding socket.io as if I navigate to page localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js, there is nothing there as I would expect... I have also tried adding the CORS headers into the application rb rile without the middleware/rack gem, but it makes no difference. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you would want to append "http" -- or whatever the protocol is -- to your urls that your are trying to connect to.

Second, instead of referencing `localhost` reference `127.0.0.1`. Still reference the port number as you would normally.

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost:2013');
```

Would become:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:2013');
```

Edit: This would only work if your servers are assigned different IP addresses for some reason. That being said, you would still want to add the protocol to your urls anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but still get the same issue :/ I restarted the rails server and node, but still have both error messages. I'm just trying to check if there is something dodgy in how I set up socket.io....

Comment: Yea, it sounds like the socket.io library is not being pulled in properly. Try it with a CDN version of it and see if that helps anything. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io

Comment: Actually, on Chrome console I get this `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:2013/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LR1sHeT. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.` and that socket.io link does take you to socket io...so it does look a little like it actaully is an access issue...